# Changing Arabic diacritics color with spannable string is not working on some phones

Tags: android, spannablestring

I used this code to change the color of Arabic diacritics:

```
List<String> arabicV = Arrays.asList("ؘ","ؙ","ؚ","ؐ","ؐؑ","ؒ","ؓ","ؔ","ؕ","ؖ","ؗ","ؗ","ﹰﹰ","ﹲ","ﹴ","ﹸ","ﹼ","ﹾ",
            "ٍ","ً","ُ","ِ","َ","ّ","ٓ","ٔ","ْ","ِ","َّ","َ","َْ","َ","ً","ٌ","َ","ُ","ٍ"
            ,"َ","ْ","ِ","ُ","ّ","ً");

    for (int j = 0; j < myString.length; j++) {
        if (arabicV.contains(myString.substring(j, j + 1))) {
             wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")),
                                        j, j+1 , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                            }

                        }
```

it is working fine on my device like this:

[image]

but on some devices (like LG-G5) it is not working. like this:

[image]

does anyone know how to fix this Or any other alternative ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my answer, there is a way to make it right on all devices:

```
SpannedString result = new SpannedString("");
            for (int j=0;j<myString.length();j++){
                Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(myString.substring(j,j+1));
                if (arabicV.contains(myString.substring(j,j+1))) {
                    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")),
                            0, 1, 0);

                }
                else
                {
                    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor( "#000000")),
                            0, 1, 0);
                }
                result = (SpannedString) TextUtils.concat(result,"",wordtoSpan);
            }
```